# Class implementing IEventDispatcher cannot use Event metadata tag

Tags: apache-flex, events, metadata

Okay Flex gurus, we have following class

```
package
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    import flash.events.IEventDispatcher;

    import mx.controls.Alert;
    import mx.core.IMXMLObject;

    [Event(name="progressReady", type="flash.events.Event")]
    public class IndependentClass implements IMXMLObject, IEventDispatcher{
            public var dispatcher:IEventDispatcher;

            public function initialized(document:Object, id:String):void{
                    dispatcher = document as EventDispatcher;
                    addEventListener("progressReady", progressReadyListener);
            }

            public function progressReadyListener(e:Event):void{
                    Alert.show("progressReadyListener inside");
            }

            public function click():void{
                    dispatchEvent(new Event("progressReady", true));
            }

            public function addEventListener(type:String, listener:Function, useCapture:Boolean=false, priority:int=0, useWeakReference:Boolean=false):void{
                    if(dispatcher != null){
                            dispatcher.addEventListener(type, listener, useCapture, priority, useWeakReference);
                    }
            }

            public function dispatchEvent(event:Event):Boolean{
                    if(dispatcher != null){
                            return dispatcher.dispatchEvent(event);
                    }
                    return false;
            }

            public function hasEventListener(type:String):Boolean{
                    if(dispatcher != null){
                            return dispatcher.hasEventListener(type);
                    }
                    return false;
            }

            public function removeEventListener(type:String, listener:Function, useCapture:Boolean=false):void{
                    if(dispatcher != null){
                            dispatcher.removeEventListener(type, listener, useCapture);
                    }
            }

            public function willTrigger(type:String):Boolean{
                    if(dispatcher != null){
                            return dispatcher.willTrigger(type);
                    }
                    return false;
            }
       }

    }
```

And we have following MXML markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
           xmlns:local="*">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        protected function progressHandler():void{
            Alert.show("progressHandler outside");
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <local:IndependentClass id="ic" progressReady="progressHandler()"/>
</fx:Declarations>

<s:Button click="{ic.click()}"/>
</s:Application>
```

If you run these, you'll notice that the MXML-component can't hear the event. The question is simple, is there some way of getting the Event-metadata tag to work WITHOUT extending EventDispatcher? I would like to keep this class independent and use object composition as much as possible.

And no, I don't want to use ActionScript addEventListener in the MXML-file. It doesn't tell the developer anything like good old Event metadata tag, and besides, that is not the point of this example. :)

Hopefully someone can enlighten what the event metadata tag does behind the curtains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. To make your code working ypu should change your main class like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:local="*" xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" creationComplete="init()">

    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;

        protected function progressHandler():void
        {
            Alert.show("progressHandler outside");
        }

        protected function init():void
        {
            addEventListener("progressReady", progressReadyHandler);
        }

        private function progressReadyHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            progressHandler();
        }
    ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <local:IndependentClass id="ic" />
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:Button click="{ic.click()}" />
</s:Application>
```

The problem is you didn't set object which dispatches events properly. In your case this object is still main application class. To reach your aim your should recreate your `IndependentClass` like the following:

```
package
{
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
import flash.events.IEventDispatcher;

import mx.controls.Alert;

[Event(name="progressReady", type="flash.events.Event")]
public class ProperIndependentClass implements IEventDispatcher
{
    public function ProperIndependentClass()
    {
        // This line initialized dispatching making this object target and currentTarget of the event
        dispatcher = new EventDispatcher(this);
        addEventListener("progressReady", progressReadyListener);
    }

    private var dispatcher:EventDispatcher;

    public function addEventListener(type:String, listener:Function, useCapture:Boolean = false, priority:int = 0,
                                     useWeakReference:Boolean = false):void
    {
        dispatcher.addEventListener(type, listener, useCapture, priority);
    }

    public function click():void
    {
        dispatchEvent(new Event("progressReady", true));
    }

    public function hasEventListener(type:String):Boolean
    {
        return dispatcher.hasEventListener(type);
    }

    public function removeEventListener(type:String, listener:Function, useCapture:Boolean = false):void
    {
        dispatcher.removeEventListener(type, listener, useCapture);
    }

    public function willTrigger(type:String):Boolean
    {
        return dispatcher.willTrigger(type);
    }

    public function dispatchEvent(evt:Event):Boolean
    {
        return dispatcher.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }

    public function progressReadyListener(e:Event):void
    {
        Alert.show("progressReadyListener inside");
    }
}
}
```

I've commented the line in constructor which performs all the magic. More details are available [in official documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/IEventDispatcher.html?filter_flex=4.5&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2.5).

So your main class will look like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:local="*" xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;

        protected function progressHandler():void
        {
            Alert.show("progressHandler outside");
        }
    ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <local:ProperIndependentClass id="ic" progressReady="progressHandler()" />
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:Button click="{ic.click()}" />
</s:Application>
```

And what about `[Event]` metatag. It is nothing than a compile time annotation which helps compiler to validate MXML tags attributes. Another usage of this metatag is offering events code completion by IDE (both in MXML and in ActionScript when you're typing `addEventListener`). It hasn't any influence at runtime.

P.S. And Jeffry is right saying you should just extend `EventDispatcher`. The purpose of `IEventDispatcher` is if your class inherits some other class which is not derived from `EventDispatcher`. In this case you can use composition to solve the problem of event dispatching. In your case your `IndependentClass` hasn't any requirements to not inherit from `EventDispatcher`.

Answer (score 0):

> Event-metadata tag to work WITHOUT
>   extending EventDispatcher

As far as I know, the event metadata tag does only two things.  It tells code hinting that the component may dispatch the event; or it is used for generating ASDocs.  I would expect you'll be able to use the metadata tag without extending EventDispatcher; however I do not believe your component will be able to dispatch an event without extending EventDispatcher or creating your own Event Dispatcher system.  I think [AS3 Signals](https://github.com/robertpenner/as3-signals/wiki/) is an alternative Event Dispatching System.

> I don't want to use ActionScript
>   addEventListener in the MXML-file. It
>   doesn't tell the developer anything
>   like good old Event metadata tag,

The addEventListener method is a way to add an event listener to a component.
The metadata tag is a way to tell code hinting that this component may dispatch the event.
They serve very different purposes; and using one does not negate the need for the other.

I believe that addresses your questions.  My personal approach is to extend EventDispatcher if the class needs to dispatch events.

Comment: Hey, thanks for response. I'm aware of the use cases of addEventListener and Event metadata. The point I was trying to make was that Event-metadata tells the final developer (component user) directly what kind of events component dispatches (they show up in IDE) while addEventListener does not (you have to look the documentation). As a follow-up question, do you see any benefits (that you didn't already address) extending EventDispatcher has over composing it like Constantiner? Any pitfalls?

Comment: @Jukka Hämäläinen Your words are true; but I honestly don't understand your point.  I could also say that the "Event-metadata tells the component user directly what kind of events the component dispatches; but the use of a createChildren method does not."  Such a statement is true; but still compares completely unrelated items.  Beyond that; it seems like composing is better use of encapsulation than inheritance.  But, I have no further thoughts on that.